# Android version nativescript

Tags: android, configuration, nativescript

I have got android sdk installed and set android_home. In fact I'm developing with ionic and everything is ok.

Now I want to test nativescript but I'm not able to configure it. I installed everything and I get the error:

*You need to have Android SDK 22 or later and the latest Android Support Repository installed on your system.*

I have android 23 version installed and also 19. I installed also 22 as I read in other pages that nativescript have a problem even if you have an upper version, but even with andorid 22 it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which OS are you using? Have you installed also Android support repositories from SDK manager?

I have installed Android SDK tools from version 19 to 23, SDK platform-tools and SDK build-tools.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I read about android support repositories but I didn't find it till now. :/ I should notice it first u.u